# why does value = string

Tags: python

```
import requests as req

def urls(topic):


urls("tacos")
```

Python 2 runtime.

Need help debugging

Many thanks!

Comment: you can use beautifulsoup for achieving your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach without using BeautifulSoup would be:

```
import requests as req

def getTopicCount(topic):
    resp = req.request(method='GET', url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=%s" % (topic))
    print "Total Occurrence",resp.json()["parse"]["text"]["*"].count(topic)

getTopicCount("train")
```

Output:

```
Total Occurrence 24
```